# Switching data of attribute of one table to attribute of other table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need help regarding a rails project. I am new to rails, and I am making a quiz application. I have created everything.

For the model `User_relation_MC_question`, I have attribute user_id answer and user_pick. I need to import the `answer` from the existing `MC_question` model, but I have no idea how to do this.

I have tried:

- https://human-se.github.io/rails-demos-n-deets-2020/demo-has-many-forms/
- https://tressa-sanders.medium.com/building-a-quiz-with-ruby-on-rails-using-multiple-instances-of-a-model-88e506832af9
- https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to

This is my MC-question migration file that I want to use the answer column in it as a column for other module with value I already have in this module

```rb
class CreateMcQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :mc_questions do |t|
      t.string :question
      t.string :answer
      t.string :distractor_1
      t.string :distractor_2

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This is the second model I want to use the column+data data of answer from mc_question table to this user_r_mc_question model:

```rb
class CreateUserRMcQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :user_r_mc_questions do |t|
      t.string :User_ID
      t.string :answer
      t.string :user_choice

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**The attribute answer with value in the second model.**

Kindly help me in this so i can learn from this.

Comment: Please share the code and some examples of what you want to do to be able to help you

Comment: class CreateMcQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :mc_questions do |t|
      t.string :question
      t.string :answer
      t.string :distractor_1
      t.string :distractor_2

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
This is my Mc_question migrated file i want the answer attribute in this to use in some other module same with the value

Comment: if you can put 3 back-ticks (the backwards single-quote mark) around your code blocks (3 on the line before and 3 on the line after) it should keep the code together to make it more readable. I can't edit your post as the "edit queue is full"

Comment: @Jad check now please

Comment: Hey @Abu Bakar, yes the format is pretty good now, but still I feel there is an information missing, plz share the structure of the other model that you want to use that column in, and how you need to use it

Comment: @AbdUlRahmanShawareb please check

Comment: Yes it's more clear now, do you have any association between the 2 models? @AbuBakar

Comment: @AbdUlRahmanShawareb no bro

Comment: I've just looked back over your question, and I think I understand it better now.   You have lots of models (although you haven't included the code for the models in your question) and you want to copy the data from one model to another model (rather than linking the models together)?

Comment: @Jad yes it is, I want to copy data form one model to another

Comment: @AbuBakar Sorry for my lateness, if possible can you include sections from your actual model, and your controller, so that we can give relevant examples of how to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

You may find this article helpful https//api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to

Comment: Hi @manibi101 please don't just provide links, do include extracts of the article you're referencing, as this question and answer may be around for years to come, and the article may not. (unlikely, but the general rule is that you should).  can you also expand your answer to give practical examples for the questioner?